# What is the DLR Layer Responsibility?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic-language-runtime

What is the DLR Layer Responsibility?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between CLR and DLR in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184162/what-is-the-difference-between-clr-and-dlr-in-c)

Comment: this question is not duplicate. please more attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052.aspx.

> The purpose of the DLR is to enable a system of dynamic languages to run on the .NET Framework and give them .NET interoperability. The DLR introduces dynamic objects to C# and Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2010 to support dynamic behavior in these languages and enable their interoperation with dynamic languages.

Answer (score 0):

"DLR" is here for supporting dynamic languages - in other words interpreted ones - in the Microsoft .NET Framework.